# jasper report cross tab condition in measures

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I am working in JasperSoft studio 6.2

Here is a simple report with one cross tab (a mock up from the real issue). I want to add a condition in the measure, so that when the currency is gbp, the val should be multiplied by 3. But this seems not happening, the measure just shows the val regardless the currency.

This is what the report is showing now:

[image]

The cell at c1 and r2 should be 3, so is the cell at the c2 and r2

The expression for the measure

```
    $F{currency} == "gbp"? $F{val}*3 : $F{val}
```

The dataset query

```
    select 'c1' as cg,  'r1' as rg, 1 as val, 'aud' as currency
    union all select 'c1' as cg,  'r2' as rg, 1 as val, 'gbp' as currency
    union all select 'c2' as cg,  'r1' as rg, 1 as val, 'aud' as currency
    union all select 'c2' as cg,  'r2' as rg, 1 as val, 'gbp' as currency
```

The report:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
    <!-- 2016-05-10T10:19:28 -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test6" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="472d0a21-f9e0-4b4c-8830-53ce76baca95">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datamart"/>
        <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select 'c1' as cg,  'r1' as rg, 1 as val, 'aud' as currency
    union all select 'c1' as cg,  'r2' as rg, 1 as val, 'gbp' as currency
    union all select 'c2' as cg,  'r1' as rg, 1 as val, 'aud' as currency
    union all select 'c2' as cg,  'r2' as rg, 1 as val, 'gbp' as currency]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="cg" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="rg" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="val" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="currency" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <summary>
            <band height="220" splitType="Stretch">
                <crosstab>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="200" uuid="db69b441-d09f-49f7-b290-7eec7275eb1b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <rowGroup name="rg1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{rg}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="6f2b3dc8-ae54-4dd9-b74d-8f708dfe0e52"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{rg1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabRowHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="23c06ac5-0336-4dec-a4f1-6a9e48d9b470"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total rg1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    </rowGroup>
                    <columnGroup name="cg1" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{cg}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="9872abc3-cac8-4b20-8dac-8f3d294d6c0d"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{cg1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fc087f0f-321d-46eb-b4ac-44eea96ff044"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total cg1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    </columnGroup>
                    <measure name="val_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                        <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{currency} == "gbp"? $F{val}*3 : $F{val}]]></measureExpression>
                    </measure>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="827bc665-96dc-4adc-9a75-e4549d146d79"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="cg1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4d85b6d3-b844-4072-aa29-d33559efd678"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="rg1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f83e2d2f-ad1f-47e7-ac36-567f47862219"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="rg1" columnTotalGroup="cg1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="668927e0-801e-415d-ab82-36040ad4f830"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                </crosstab>
            </band>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you please try this $F{currency}.equals("gbp") ? $F{val}*3 : $F{val} ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum you are right! Can you please put that in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F{currency}.equals("gbp") ? $F{val}*3 : $F{val}

You can search the difference between == and .equals.